# Mysql query to Identify the corrupted data

Tags: sql, mysql

Table 1: temp1 with columns id: int, tags: varchar;

Data of temp1 table:-

| id | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ,a,b,c, |
| 2 | ,a,d,e, |
| 3 | ,a,d,f,e, |

Table 2: temp2 with columns id: int, references: varchar

Data of temp2 table:-

| id | references |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {valuesMeta: ['a','b','c','d']} |

expected result

| id | corruptedTags |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | f,e |

Here I want a query of mysql which should return the above expected result.
Explanation:-
Here temp1 table contains the tags that are available in the valuesMeta of references column of temp2 table. But somehow data get corrupted and temp1 table contains the tags which are not available in the valuesMeta. So I want all the recordId which contains the corrupted data and also if possible, provide the tags which are corrupted.

Comment: has the temp table only 1 row ? and which version you are using ?

Comment: Provide source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: @BerndBuffen temp1 table has multiple rows, but tamp2 table has 1 row.

Comment: Have you already attempted any code? Got stuck somewhere?

Comment: @Aman Gupta - and which MySQL Version ??

Comment: @BerndBuffen Mysql version is 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one querie for you.

```
SELECT temp1.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM( BOTH ',' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', n), ',', -1))) AS corruptedTags
FROM temp1
JOIN (
  SELECT 2 AS n UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7
) AS numbers ON CHAR_LENGTH(tags) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tags, ',', '')) >= n
inner JOIN temp2 ON temp2.id = 1 
AND LOCATE(CONCAT('"',TRIM( BOTH ',' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', n), ',', -1)),'"'),temp2.`references`) = 0
GROUP BY temp1.id
ORDER by id;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM temp1;
+----+-----------+
| id | tags      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | ,a,b,c,   |
|  2 | ,a,d,e,   |
|  3 | ,a,d,f,e, |
+----+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM temp2;
+----+-----------------------------------+
| id | references                        |
+----+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | {"valuesMeta": ["a","b","c","d"]} |
+----+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT temp1.id,
    -> GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM( BOTH ',' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', n), ',', -1))) AS corruptedTags
    -> FROM temp1
    -> JOIN (
    ->   SELECT 2 AS n UNION ALL
    ->   SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    ->   SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    ->   SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    ->   SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    ->   SELECT 7
    -> ) AS numbers ON CHAR_LENGTH(tags) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tags, ',', '')) >= n
    -> inner JOIN temp2 ON temp2.id = 1 
    -> AND LOCATE(CONCAT('"',TRIM( BOTH ',' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', n), ',', -1)),'"'),temp2.`references`) = 0
    -> GROUP BY temp1.id
    -> ORDER by id;
+----+---------------+
| id | corruptedTags |
+----+---------------+
|  2 | e             |
|  3 | f,e           |
+----+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

**NOTE** I have change temp2 to a valid JSON string

please let me know is it working for you